# How do I get the text from 0+n columns in a UserForm List Box?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

So this is for a purchase order data entry application where the user enters each item from a PO into the UserForm listbox with different attributes of the item in each column. For example:

Column 1: Name of the product
Column 2: Qty purchased
Column 3: Price

Everything works great, but I cannot get the values out of the 0+n columns in the list box. I've only found this code, but it only gets me the text value for the *n*th column:

```
ListBox1.ListIndex = n
MsgBox ListBox1.Text
```

I can get the value for (n, column 0), which I need.
But I also need the value of (n, column 1), (n, column 2), etc.

Help!!!

Comment: Sorry.Correction:  it only gets me the text value for column 0 of the nth row**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify column number and row number to return value from `ListBox` control. Below is simple code to return value from 3rd column, 3rd row.

> ***Note:*** ListBox indexing always start from zero (0).

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim iCol As Long
Dim iRow As Long

    iCol = 2 'Specify column number
    iRow = 2 'Specify row number

    MsgBox ListBox1.List(iRow, iCol)

End Sub
```

If you want to loop through all elements then you have to use a `For` loop. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40612209/5514747) for details.

Comment: What!? I could have sworn I tried that. Anyways, it works great! Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

### Get values from columns in multicolumn listbox

You can use the List property of the listbox to get the values from the other columns.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim n As Long

    ' get random number to pull example data from listbox
    n = Application.Randbetween(0, ListBox1.ListCount-1)

    ' Column 1 - name of product
    MsgBox ListBox1.List(n, 0)

    ' Column 2 = Quantity purchased
    MsgBox ListBox1.List(n, 1)


    ' Column 3 = Price
    MsgBox ListBox1.List(n, 2)

End Sub
```

Note, the column that ListBox1.Text and ListBox1.Value return values from is determined by the listbox's BoundColumn and TextColumn respectively.